# Which outdoor filaments for unheated beds?

Tags: filament, filament-choice

I am searching for 3D printing filaments, that are suitable for outdoor purposes, but printable on unheated beds.

I will mostly use it for sensor node enclosures (should withstand temperature up to 50°C/120°F) and car accessories (70°C/160°F).

If it requires annealing, it should have low shrinkage, since I will be printing parts that will fit into each other.

Answer (score 4):

Considering your temperature requirements PETG could be used on unheated beds.

High operational temperatures for your products requires filaments with a high [glass transition temperature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_transition) (the point where the plastic becomes soft). A filament with a high glass transition temperature causes filament to shrink considerably when the bed is not heated (as when the bed it heated, the plastic is soft and withstands the shrinkage stresses better). Basically, your requirements are in contradiction. You should be using a heated bed and ABS, or a high temperature resistant filament like a co-polyester.

*Example of filament comparison*
[image: Comparison of common and co-polyester filaments]

If a heated bed is no option, PETG is you most likely candidate for printing as many filament manufacturing brands say that a heated bed is optional. My personal experience is that PETG very much likes a heated bed, getting it to stick at lower temperatures is more difficult.

Comment: note to the point of PLA and Ability to print transparent parts: Yes it is possible, i have 2 transparent PLA filaments by my own.

Comment: @Horitsu To print really transparent, see [this](https://learn.colorfabb.com/lets-make-something-clear/)

Answer (score 4):

PETG is good for your project.
You can also print transparent ABS on unheated bed with ABS juice.I tried transparent ABS in outside environment and it work fine.I live in India where outdoor temperature reach to 45C in summer.It is easy to print small parts.ABS juice may or may not work with large parts depending on your ambient room temperature.Ambient room temp should be above 30C for ABS on unheated bed.I suggest you to use a enclosure for printer if you are in cold area.